# toggling of text is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs for canvas. There is a feature where user can add text which has a switch button. When the switch is on, the text is dispalyed in the canvas where user can change the text. But when the switch is off, the text is not removed.

Here is my code

```
addText = val => {
  console.log("val", val);
  if (val.checked) {
    let text = new fabric.IText("Double click me to change the text!", {
      fontSize: 28,
      fontWeight: 600,
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: "black",
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    this.state.canvas.add(text);
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    <div className="image-board">
      <Grid container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <canvas
              id="canvas"
              ref={el => (this.canvasEl = el)}
              width={500}
              height={400}
              className="z-depth-1"
            />
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={6}>
            <Filter
              addText={this.addText}
              addSubtitle={this.addSubtitle}
              opacityChange={this.opacityChange}
              applyTextFilter={this.applyTextFilter}
              applyColor={this.applyColor}
              applyBlur={this.applyBlur}
            />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
}


class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-options">
        <div>
          Show Title
          <Checkbox toggle onChange={(e, val) => this.props.addText(val)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          Show Subtitle
          <Checkbox toggle onChange={(e, val) => this.props.addSubtitle(val)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Text;
```

Comment: what is `this.state.canvas`?

Comment: its the instance of canvas class which has following object klass
`backgroundImage
:
klass
cacheCanvasEl
:
canvas
contextCache
:
CanvasRenderingContext2D
contextContainer
:
CanvasRenderingContext2D
contextTop
:
CanvasRenderingContext2D
freeDrawingBrush
:
klass
height
:
400
lowerCanvasEl
:
canvas#canvas.z-depth-1.lower-canvas
targets
:
Array(0)
upperCanvasEl
:
canvas.upper-canvas.z-depth-1
viewportTransform
:
Array(6)
vptCoords
:
Object
width
:
500`

Comment: Please don't include code or large information in the comment. If you need to clarify, just edit your question And what you mean by `But when the switch is off, the text is not removed`

Comment: Sorry i was not aware about this. I have seen a lot of time the code been shown in the comment that is why i did so. I apologize for my mistake. The switch is a checkbox. When checked should show text which is working but when unchecked, the text should be removed from canvas.

Comment: You could simple set the visibility of the text, use `setVisible` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html

Comment: I shifted my text object above if condition and there i add the property setVisible: val.checked but the text is still shown when unchecked.

Comment: Well how are you even passing the `val` `onChange` anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145594/discussion-between-pythonbeginner-and-a-lau).